# MariaDB upgrade on Red Hat blocked on the installing v10.9.2 due to missing package pv

Tags: mariadb, redhat

The [MariaDB upgrade](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/upgrading-between-major-mariadb-versions/) of MariaDB seem to follow the same behaviour pattern of removing the old version, keeping the data, then installing the new version, such as [Upgrading from MariaDB 10.3 to MariaDB 10.4](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/upgrading-from-mariadb-103-to-mariadb-104/), and the other version to version procedures are the same.

When upgrading from v10.3 to v10.9 on an RHEL 7 host, the process errored when installing the new version, saying, `Error: Package: MariaDB-server-10.9.2-1.el7.centos.x86_64 (mariadb) Requires: pv`.

I am new to the upgrade process, so I will highly appreciate any hints or suggestions.

**Full screenshot:**

```
[root@hostname lib]# yum install MariaDB-server MariaDB-client MariaDB-backup MariaDB-shared
Loaded plugins: product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package MariaDB-backup.x86_64 0:10.9.2-1.el7.centos will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libpmem.so.1(LIBPMEM_1.0)(64bit) for package: MariaDB-backup-10.9.2-1.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: MariaDB-common for package: MariaDB-backup-10.9.2-1.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpmem.so.1()(64bit) for package: MariaDB-backup-10.9.2-1.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libpcre2-8.so.0()(64bit) for package: MariaDB-backup-10.9.2-1.el7.centos.x86_64
---> Package MariaDB-client.x86_64 0:10.9.2-1.el7.centos will be installed
---> Package MariaDB-server.x86_64 0:10.9.2-1.el7.centos will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: galera-4 for package: MariaDB-server-10.9.2-1.el7.centos.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: pv for package: MariaDB-server-10.9.2-1.el7.centos.x86_64
---> Package MariaDB-shared.x86_64 0:10.9.2-1.el7.centos will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package MariaDB-common.x86_64 0:10.9.2-1.el7.centos will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: MariaDB-compat for package: MariaDB-common-10.9.2-1.el7.centos.x86_64
---> Package MariaDB-server.x86_64 0:10.9.2-1.el7.centos will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: pv for package: MariaDB-server-10.9.2-1.el7.centos.x86_64
---> Package galera-4.x86_64 0:26.4.12-1.el7.centos will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: socat for package: galera-4-26.4.12-1.el7.centos.x86_64
---> Package libpmem.x86_64 0:1.5.1-2.1.el7 will be installed
---> Package pcre2.x86_64 0:10.23-2.el7 will be installed
--> Running transaction check
---> Package MariaDB-compat.x86_64 0:10.9.2-1.el7.centos will be installed
---> Package MariaDB-server.x86_64 0:10.9.2-1.el7.centos will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: pv for package: MariaDB-server-10.9.2-1.el7.centos.x86_64
---> Package socat.x86_64 0:1.7.3.2-2.el7 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: MariaDB-server-10.9.2-1.el7.centos.x86_64 (mariadb)
           Requires: pv
**********************************************************************
yum can be configured to try to resolve such errors by temporarily enabling
disabled repos and searching for missing dependencies.
To enable this functionality please set 'notify_only=0' in /etc/yum/pluginconf.d/search-disabled-repos.conf
**********************************************************************

Error: Package: MariaDB-server-10.9.2-1.el7.centos.x86_64 (mariadb)
           Requires: pv
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
[root@hostname lib]#
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`pv` is in the [EPEL](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/epel/) repository.

One you enable this repository, pv will be pulled in as the dependency from there.

Comment: Thank you, @danblack. I installed the EPEL repository first and then installed the MariaDB new version without any problem.

Answer (score 1):

1. installed the EPEL repository:

   ```
   yum install epel-release -y
   ```
2. installed the MariaDB

Answer (score 0):

The *process* I used was:

- Install pv dependency of galley. The command is:

  ```
  yum install epel-release -y
  ```
- after installing this dependency:
  download from repository
  [wget](https://downloads.mariadb/MariaDB/mariadb_repo_setup)
- Assign execution permissions:

  ```
  chmod +x mariadb_repo_setup
  ```
- Start setup:: ./mariadb_repo_setup
- Install the server:

  ```
  sudo yum install mysql-server
  ```
- Start MariaDB:

  ```
  systemctl start mariadb
  ```
- Check if the service is running:

  ```
  systemctl status mariadb
  ```
- Enable MariaDB:

  ```
  systemctl enable mariadb
  ```
- Command to start the administration interface by console: mysql